# Define a foreign key on a CLR type or not define

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

What is the best practice in entity framework:

1.Define a foreign key on a CLR type

```
public class Book
{
    public int AuthorId{get;set;}
    public Author Author{get;set;}
}
```

2.Not define a foreign key(only define navigation property)

```
public class Book
{
    public Author Author{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use define the FK and to set the key value (`AuthorId`) when defining the relationship.

There's 2 great article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx) by Julie Lerman that explain some of the benefits of taking this approach.

Here's the summary:

> **Save the Grief and Use That Foreign Key**
>
> Rather than setting the navigation property and having to worry about the state of the [related entity], just set the [Id] property, because you do have access to that value in the [related entity] instance. This is something I find myself frequently suggesting to developers. Even on Twitter, I see the question: “Why is EF inserting data that already exists?” And I often guess correctly in reply: “Any chance u r setting a navigation property on a new entity instead of an FK? J”